# The default EbeanServer has not been defined?

Tags: playframework

PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer()

Hi, I am getting above exception.i am trying to write sql query like

```
String sql = "select r.cpu as cpu, r.ram as ram, r.core as core"+"from res r,env e,env_reser"+"where e.node =1 and e.host= 1 and e.apps= 1 and er.eid=e.eid and r.rid=er.rid";
SqlRow bug = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql)
.setParameter("h",1)
.setParameter("n",1 )
.setParameter("a",1 )
.findUnique();
```

in Models package res.java file.

If i comment above code error disappears.
Can anybody plz help me.

Thanku

Comment: In your `<applicationfolder>/conf/application.conf` file do you have a line like: `ebean.default="models.*"` ?

Answer (score 4):

As said in the docs under the section [Persist Tasks in the Database](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaTodoList) (the section is about 3/4's down the page), the ebean default server can be connected to the models packages by adding the following line to you `conf/application.conf` file:

```
ebean.default = "models.*"
```